# Does python's setuptools support the `__name__ == "__main__"` style of execution?

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm just getting into packaging with setuptools, and it seems that the recommended way to install a python script along with one's module is to specify a script name that calls the name of a function, like this:

```
setup(
    # ...
    entry_points = {
        "console_scripts": [
            "script_name": "project.main:main",
        ],
    }
)
```

This clearly precludes the standard way of making a python module executable, which is (last time I checked, which was a while ago) to use `if __name__ == "__main__": do_stuff()`. Does setuptools support this style, or should I switch to defining a main function and specifying it in entry_points?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is: `"script_name = project.main:do_stuff`  with setuptools

Setuptools creates scripts named `script_name` that imports and runs the function `project.main:do_stuff`, not run the script directly.  You should re-read [this part](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#automatic-script-creation) ([alternate link](http://packages.python.org/distribute/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation), if you use Distribute) of the setuptools docs again to understand why it's this way. The script it creates contains `if __name__ == "__main__"` still. So yes, this is still the defacto way of making it execute.

This is a copy of easy_install installed with setuptools

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'distribute==0.6.14','console_scripts','easy_install'
__requires__ = 'distribute==0.6.14'
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(
        load_entry_point('distribute==0.6.14', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
    )
```

I think it's best to define an entry point and a script similar to easy_install. That imports and uses the entry point, like you show in your example `if __name__ == "__main__": do_stuff()`. It's great for debugging and early testing, also if you use [distutils](http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html), there is no need to add/change anything. You can also have another app to call do_stuff() to access your app with out the overhead of running it in the shell, which is what setuptools is doing, distutils copy's the script.

Comment: How do you treat the difference in `__name__` for a local deployment/development vs deploy from pypi when using logging ? I seem not be able to use the preffered `logging.getLogger(__name__)` as it yields "`__main__`" on local dev and "`<project>.<module>`" for setuptools install.